# Why are mobs spawning on my roof?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

On Minecraft PE I have a small wooden house with a mine inside and wooden flooring

But would there be any reason for mobs to spawn on my roof of the house?
[image: ground view]
[image: view from above]

Comment: Any possibility of getting a screenshot?  That could help us see what the problem is.

Comment: I tried to but it does not work

Comment: A better shot of the roof itself might help.  We could see if there's any portion of it that might not be illuminated.

Comment: OK I will do that

Comment: You can make a stack of dirt to stand on though.

Comment: @T-u-s-t-y It looks like you just didn't have your post formatted properly.  That's fine.  You had the link to the image, but no markup to actually display it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To eliminate a few possibilities:

- If it's spiders, spiders will climb onto your house roof and wait for you to exit to jump on you.  It's annoying, and the reason why I always leave my house running and screaming.
- The coal(!) you have placed near your door would allow a mob to jump up onto it, then onto your roof. Mobs can jump surprisingly high.
- Your roof might not be illuminated enough.  Light it up with more torches than you think are necessary.  Roofs are notorious for being hard to light.

Comment: It's not obsidian it's coal also endermen are not in pe yet

Comment: I...did not even know you could MAKE a solid block of coal.

Comment: Edited all the same, since Endermen won't be a problem.

Comment: @Zibbobz the latest pe patch introduced blocks of coal